# change avi playback speed and sound (maybe using ffmpeg)

Tags: video, speed, ffmpeg, playback, headers

I have a video file of 5 FPS / 8000Hz that I want to speed up 6 times. I want the pitch and playback to increase - can I do this by simply adjusting the file header?

I can't seem to figure out the right parameters to do this with ffmpeg since it actually creates new frames in order to stay at the same speed. I read some similar topics on this website, but can't seem to find anything simple to do with both sound and image.

Is there a way to do this with a command-line tool or can someone explain how to alter this in code?

Answer (score 1):

mencoder has an option to change the speed. A similar question was answered [here](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/286989-%5BSOLVED%5D-fast-action-with-ffmpeg-or-Cinelerra).

The following command was suggested:

```
mencoder file.avi -speed 20 -vf scale=720:368,hqdn3d=3:2:3:2,expand=720:480 -ovc xvid -oac pcm -xvidencopts fixed_quant=2 -o out.avi )
```